# Preg_match or class including

Tags: php, regex, oop

I'm building a framework for my site and I wanted to create a model loader and I  wondered what is better -
To enter the file name and find the class name by regex and then declare it or,
Set class name as the file name and declare it as it is?

Comment: Could you be more specific?  Examples are good.  Also, while I love regex, they're not the tool for every job, and have some overhead associated with them that it seems you can probably do without, here.

Comment: What do you mean by "better"?

Comment: You seems to have a misconception of what model is.

Comment: @tereško, why do you talk about misconception? He talks about how to load a class, not where or about module class contents. What do you mean with misconception?

Comment: He talks about MVC pattern. @tereško I searched the internet for MVC and that's what I found.

Comment: I think that @tereško talks about usage of model or library word. Models are PHP classes that are designed to work with information in your data. But the concept that you underline was load method of a class, it wasn't?

Comment: the prime model class(model.php) is loading only models that way :
$model->email->get_emails();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com/) uses same name about class and its file. I think that this method is simple and effective: you could immediately see which classes you have without opening the files and load classes without too many commands.